# What is the magnetic lines of force for rotor with N/S pole?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

All illustrations of direction of force in motor has this form.

[image]

For the following, i'm confused where is the direction of force. It uses winding and there seems to be current and force in every side of the winding. So where does it really point?

[image]

This is video of the motor running.

https://d2y5sgsy8bbmb8.cloudfront.net/v2/81452c76-74b7-518f-b13f-44f94905798f/ShortForm-Generic-480p-16-9-1409173089793-rpcbe5.mp4

It's from amazon science kit. [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073GXWQMV/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A243HB0NZWY05K&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073GXWQMV)

Comment: Please provide a more detail if you’d like an answer. Where do you think the lines of force are? What is your conceptual difficulty in answering this question?

Comment: I don't know the lines of force. It's part of an actual motor high school kit i bought at amazon see ...  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073GXWQMV/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A243HB0NZWY05K&psc=1

Comment: So how do you think this thing works?

Comment: The north is attracted to the south of the rotor.. but i don't know how to use Lorentz force or left hand rule in it.. so asking where is the direction of the magnetic field and lorentz force.. if anyone knows how to draw.. pls. overlap it to the 2nd picture so i can understand in the context of most youtube videos which use the first picture tnx

Comment: There is no link to that YT video.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxG3cwugXgs

Comment: pls look at this illustration i made for my amazon motor https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/1083/VubR8M.jpg  if the green is the current direction, and the yellow is the direction of force. Using left rule, the direction is correct, right? Thanks.

Comment: For current travelling in a wire, point your right thumb in the direction of the current and then wrap your fingers around the direction of your thumb. This will give you the direction of the magnetic field. Additionally, use the right hand rule by pointing your thumb in the direction of current, your index finger in the direction of the this magnetic field and then your middle finger provides the direction of the force.

Comment: I have tried doing it.. with a lot of effort. But I'm confused about something. I edited the main subject entirely with new illustrations. Please take a look at it and try to Answer, i'll comment on your Answer because we have reached limits of comments here, thank you.